# RDP crashes when another user is logged in

Tags: windows, networking, rdp, internet

I've been experiecing a problem lately with RDP. The situation:

I have 2 accounts on my Win10 Pro machine. A personal one and one for work.

I use RDP to connect to my personal account but RDP crashes when I try to connect while my work account is logged in.

Sometimes there's a screen saying something like

> Connecting to your account will log of the current logged in account

and then I can proceed but in most cases it's just crashes. It's the same if I try to do that from another win10 pro machine or from iOS app RD client.

I connect through internet to forwarded ports.

How can I setup RDP to make it automatically log off the work account and make it possible to work in the personal one?

As a workaround I set a task with the scheduler. It logs off from work account when I log in with RDP but the nuissance is that I need to connect the second time because the first time I connect it crashes and doesn't wait for the work account to log off.

Comment: What do you mean it crashes? Does it bluescreen? What happens exactly?

Comment: the RDP application just shuts down with no error or anything